# Pass date to another Form change Format

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm trying pass date to another Form But i want to pass only date not datetime.
I'm using this code:

```
// Load data from DATAGRIDVIEW To MemberForm

ss.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
ss.textBox17.Text =Convert.ToDateTime(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[19]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

But i get an error:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: What is the difference between the first line and the second one?

Comment: In the first i pass Data Type(Varchar), In Second Data type(date)

Comment: Look carefully and exclude all the code related to the conversion to DateTime

Comment: If  i will use this ss.textBox17.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[19].Value.ToString(); it pass my date + time. Example 8/5/2016 12:00:00. I want to convert it only to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a grid cell. You have to use it's value.

Try this:

```
ss.textBox17.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[19].Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Rest seems fine. It will work.